# How can restrict an IAM user to assume Cross Account roles with a specific name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Which condition can I apply to limit an IAM to only assume roles with a specific name ?

This user has a Trusted Relationship on multiple AWS accounts, which all contain a role names "MyRole". So I want a condition like:

`Assumed RoleARN ~= arn:aws:iam::[0-9]*:role/MyRole`

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To let your IAM user assume a role of specific name across multiple accounts, **white-list all the required role ARNs explicitly**. That's the **secure way** to do it.

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID1:role/MyRole",
    "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID2:role/MyRole",
    "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID3:role/MyRole"
]
```

Here's the complete policy: (*AWS-ACCOUNT-ID is 12 digit number without hypens*)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID1:role/MyRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID2:role/MyRole",
                "arn:aws:iam::AWS-ACCOUNT-ID3:role/MyRole"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, looking at your attempt of using wildcard in place of account id, I wanted to emphasize that following is possible but puts your company at security risk. It violates the [principle of least privilege](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege).

Access to assume any role in any AWS account (**INSECURE**)

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iam::*"
]
```

Access to assume 'MyRole' in any AWS account (**INSECURE**)

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:iam::*:role/MyRole"
]
```

With this wildcard access, IAM user can assume 'MyRole' (or any role) on behalf of your company in any third-party AWS account.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact this user will be used to poll data on our customers accounts. This policy aims to protect our account if some credentials leaks, and prevents them to assume all the roles on our account. The wildcard just allows us to use a single user to assume the roles on these 3rd-party accounts (and are protected with an external id).